# Spring MVC - Error handling with redirect if download not possible

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-headers

in my Spring Boot application you can download some documents, by pressing a button. This leads to the following user experience: If the user presses the button, either a download is triggered or nothing happens.

Currently, the backend is either returning the bytes or 404:

```java
@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> download() {

    Optional<byte[]> data = service.getDocumentData();

    return data.map(bytes -> new ResponseEntity<>(bytes, headers(), OK))
        .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Now we want to achieve, that the user is redirected to an error page, if no file can be downloaded.

With Spring MVC I would just return the error template like

```
public String notFound() {

    return "error/404"; // the custom template
}
```

But now I need to mix two different concerns. Returning template or returning a ResponseEntity. For this i stumbled above the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077540/spring-mvc-how-do-i-return-a-view-in-a-responseentity-method), which uses Generics. However, I don't think its a good practice. So i thought about other ways.

My first idea was to use [HTTP location header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) for redirecting on the frontend side, but I never used it before. Do you think this is a good way? Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion 1:

In the `download()` method, add `HttpServletResponse response` as the parameter and call `response.sendRedirect("http://somewhere/404.html");` when the document requested is not found.

In addition, you can also change the status code in the response as `response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);`

Suggestion 2:

Throw a custom exception, for e.g. `FileNotFoundException` and handle the exception in the `@ExceptionHandler` to return the error page in the `ResponseEntity`.

Refer - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-exceptionhandler-annotation/

Comment: And how does the `HttpServletResponse` affect my code? It is not used, instead `ResponseEntity` is still returned.

Comment: @Theiaz can you check the 2nd suggestion if the 1st one is more complicated?